# Return object that has value inside List property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an object (object1) that contains a list of other objects(List).
How do I check if the list contains a specific object(Object2) and if it does, how do I return the first object (object1)?

Some code for clarification

Domain class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Kid> Kids { get; set; } //This is the list 

    //Unimportant code
    public virtual IEnumerable<Adres> Adressen
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Emails { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Telefoonnummers { get; set; }

    public Ouder()
    {
        Kinderen = new List<Lid>();
        Adressen = new List<Adres>();
    }
}

public Parent FindByKid(int kidId)
{
    Kid kid = kids.FirstOrDefault(l => l.KidId == kidId);
    foreach(Parent parent in parents)
    {
        foreach(Kid kid in parent.Kids)
        {
            if(kid.KidId == kidId)
            {
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, I already came up with a way. But I think there has to be a way to do this in a much better way. I tried using Linq but I'm unable to come with a working solution.

Comment: Why do you think there´s a better way to do this? However this should go to review.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Because I was using a double loop while I was almost certain I could use Linq

Comment: Just a note that LINQ is basically just doing a double loop as well - so it isn't like a double-nested loop is always a bad thing.

Comment: As I mentioned a thousand times before: LINQ is not a magic loop-simplifier, it is just another syntax for the same thing. Thus when using LINQ all you do is hide the complexity of your logic which is basically not always a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it with Linq:

```
parents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Kids.Any(k => k.KidId == kidId));
```

"Give me the first parent that has any kid with the given ID"

I would also note that your first query (`Kid kid = ...`) is unnecessary since you don't use the result.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten an IEnumerable of IEnumerables using SelectMany :

```
   public Parent FindByKid(int kidId)
    {
        var kid = parents.SelectMany(p => p.Kids).FirstOrDefault(k => K.KidId == kidId);

        return kid == null ? null: kid.Parent;

    }
```

I'm on my phone so apologies for typos or formatting issues.